# Possible to expose only certain fields of an object in the Firebase DB for read access using Firebase permissions?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's consider the following structure of a JSON object literal that could represent a Firebase DB:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user0": {
      "name": "Mike",
      "age": 20,
      "relationship": "married",
      "friends": [...]
    },
    "user1": {
      "name": "Sarah",
      "age": 20,
      "relationship": "single",
      "friends": [...]      
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Using the [Firebase permission system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), is it possible to make `name` and `age` readable for *everyone* (by setting the corresponding permission to `true`) but have the `relationship` status only be visible to a more fine-grained audience, e.g. the users `friends`.

How would I have to write my `security-rules.json` to achieve this?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would have a different path for data you want all users to read and data you want only some users to read. That might seem like a pain now, but there's a good chance you're going to add to or change the attributes of a user as you continue to develop your application. Each time you do that, you'll have to add to your database security rules.

That being said, if you still want to use database security rules to handle the permissions, you can write rules for each path you want to secure. For example:

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
        "$user": {
            "relationship": {
                ".read": <some condition>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) for examples.